# Can not see some of the StaticFileExtensions

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, rider

When I try to make some configurations in Startup.cs I am not able to see some of the StaticFileExtensions.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
  
            app.UseStaticFiles();    
            app.UseFileServer();   

            app.Run(async (context) => { await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello!"); });
}
```

I am not able to invoke these methods. I am a former Windows user and now I am using JetBrains Rider on Macbook and therefore I am not able to host my project InProcess and I can understand that but I expected to be able to use all static file extension methods since they are necessary implementations.

Comment: _“I am not able to invoke these methods”_ – What exactly do you mean with that? Is it jus that you get no auto completion for them, or are you not able to compile your application with them?

Comment: No, I am not able to compile it.

Comment: what should I do? I am trying to build the project for hours

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `.csproj` file?

Comment: it's a big file. I can't share it in comment I guess

Comment: You can [edit] the question and add it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand from your comments above, since you are new on Rider you might have created an empty project. If so, be sure that the following reference is included in your project:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles

. If you already have it and still have an issue I suggest you clean the cache because I just checked an empty project and I only saw Microsoft.AspNetCore as installed. It sounds like a missing reference issue to me.

Open terminal from Rider (or command line in VS) and clean Nuget cache by this command:

> dotnet nuget locals all --clear

You may need to restart Rider to see the changes.

Comment: Referencing individual ASP.NET Core NuGet packages is somewhat discouraged since 2.1/2.2. You should use the shared framework on .NET Core.

Comment: we can't assume that they are using v2.1 or 2.2 right? that's a basic solution to figure out whether the problem is with packages or not.

Comment: Every older version other than 2.1 or 2.2 is already end-of-life and no longer supported.

Comment: just did what you say and cache clear worked for me. thank you.

Comment: @poke tbh I just checked the namespace of StaticFileExtensions on google because I have already had issues with packages many times on Mvc but I haven't developed apps on Core that much. thanks for the information though.